# Cannot install GAPPS on fresh CM12.1 on Galaxy S2

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, google

I've just done a fresh install of CM12.1 on an S2 GT-I9100, and cannot figure out how to get GAPPS on there.  Stock and mini versions fail with the `Insufficient storage space available in System partition..` error screen.  I don't understand this as it's a fresh install.  Looking at storage options shows two internal storage (partitions?) - one with 1.97 GB and the other with 11.33 Gb free space.  Does this make sense?

One method I've tried is based on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79112/resize-system-partition-of-galaxy-s-2) - to resize the partition using `Odin 3.07`, but as I'm on Mac I've had to try `JOdin3` instead **†**, which fails to detect the device.  So that method looks unworkable.

Very grateful for assistance!

---

**†** from this [source](https://builds.casual-dev.com/index.php?dir=JOdin3%2F), given the official site requires JavaFX, which doesn't work on Yosemite..

Comment: Try GAPPS [minimal](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934550851) See if it works

Comment: That fails with: `Install failed. Finding update package.. Verifying update package.. E:footer is wrong. E: signature verification failed. Installation aborted`

Answer (score 1):

Aside from XDA threads on Gapps, which can refer to dead links, especially since your device is quite old, I would recommend you to download the Gapps from [OpenGapps](http://opengapps.org), which will let you choose both the Android version, and the preferred size of the Gapps package.

Answer (score 0):

OK the only GAPPS version that seems to work is Pico - see this [XDA page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/tk-gapps-t3116347/post60921686#post60921686).

Comment: I use Nano, its pretty GOOD :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try sideloading gapps from recovery. In my case, open_gapps failed to install for odd reason that there was insufficient space in system partition - I don't know why... I was using about 10%...

eg. TWRP. Boot into TWRP Recovery, Advanced, ADB Sideload

from PC,

> adb sideload open_gapps-arm-7.1-pico-20161230.zip 
>   Total xfer: 1.28x