# Increasing Partition Size using gparted on Android Tablet

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, rom, partitions

I have a Projector Tablet running android 4.2 on an Actions gs702a (Full AOSP on Leopard SoC).
The partitions for system, data and cache made by the manufacturer are too small for my needs (and I've verified that these are different partitions of the same physical storage device). The device has root access.

Is there some way I could access the whole of the disk and use gparted to increase the size of the partition/s as there's plenty of User Available Space (29 GB) on the internal storage?

Or/and,

Is there a tool I could use to modify its firmware to make partitions of sizes of my choice?

Comment: Rooted device I take it? Or not?

Comment: Rooted, yes! I should've mentioned it. I'm editing it to show the root access status.

Comment: I think this may help: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/79112/132164. The link is more of a step-by-step tutorial so I can't really quote it much. As always, be careful doing this and make sure you've got backups of anything important.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the link. Though this doesn't apply to my device, it might be helpful in the end.