# Resize /system partition of Galaxy S4 Mini

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung, partitions

I have a Samsung S4 Mini GT-i9195 and recently I've updated it to CyanogenMod 13, it was stuck on Android 4.4.

The /system partition has 1.5GB and it was full with the stock ROM. After updating to CyanogenMod, I got only 600MB occupied and 900MB free. How can I resize the parition to, let's say 800MB, and add the remaining space to the /data partition?

I've found [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/144816/178119) for a very similar question, but I'm not sure if that procedure suits to my phone and I don't know how to create the PIT file. I'm already able to backup it from the phone and edit it with [PIT Magic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1916936). But I don't know if I can do it with this tool or even how to do it...

Any suggestions?

Comment: The **Odin** part of the procedure should be the same for all Samsung devices. The only thing that changes, though, is the PIT file: you need to grab the one that suits **perfectly** your device, meaning the one that covers any byte of the eMMC's capacity and not more than that. Regarding PIT Magic... I never was crazy enough to try that myself (and consider that adjective as a compliment), but your question made me think about it again. Since I've a S4 Mini as well, please keep me tabbed in case you make any progress, and good luck.

Comment: After some digging, I start thinking that might not be possible. I edited the PIT file with the new partition size and flashed it to the phone, but I've got the error `Uploading PIT ERROR: Failed to confirm end of PIT file transfer! ERROR: PIT upload failed!`. I suspect the file should be signed or something by Samsung and, in that case, is impossible to repartitioning the phone...

Comment: Did you pull the PIT from the phone, eh? What syntax and command did you use?

Comment: `sudo heimdall flash --repartition --pit i9195-resize.pit --RECOVERY recovery.img --no-reboot`

Comment: Maybe I was unclear... I meant *extract* the PIT *from* the phone, not *pushing* it *on* the phone.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my english...
`sudo heimdall download-pit --output i9195-stock.pit --no-reboot`

Comment: If you have **adb**, try with `adb shell "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/out.pit bs=8 count=580 skip=2176"`. Then, proceed by pulling the file from the phone with `adb pull /sdcard/out.pit ./`. If you don't have **adb**, open a terminal emulator directly on your phone, issue `su` and then `dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/out.pit bs=8 count=580 skip=2176`. Then, move **out.pit** to your computer and see if the customizations work. *Notice that /sdcard refers to where I think your internal storage is. If the location is wrong, fix it accordingly.*

Comment: Ok, but that is to extract the PIT file from the phone, I was trying to flash the new one that I've created and I got that error.

Comment: Did you create it from scratch, or did you customize the pulled one?

Comment: I customize the pulled one.

Comment: I see. Well, try to pull it manually with **dd** and customize that one. Just be careful, since **dd**, if used incorrectly, may be the acronym for **Doom & Destruction**.